# BI Publisher Add on for Word

Tags: bi-publisher, word-2007

I try to install the BI publisher add on for word 2007 but i can't use it correctly . Here is what i get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g50Co.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.

- Make sure all instances of Word are closed.
- Uninstall the BI Publisher Add-in.
- Make sure you have the latest version of the installer compatible
  with your Word version.
- Reinstall the Add-in.

reference: [Oracle community - BI Publisher](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3909619?start=15)

Comment: Hello, 
Do you any idea how the uninstall the TBAddInSetup ?

Comment: @Rida \Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\DotNetInstallFiles\ TBAddInSetup.msi or TBAddinSetup64.msi. One will give you the option to repair/remove, the other will tell you another version is installed.